# Gem5 on Mac OSX, build issue (errors)

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, gem5

I am new to gem5 and I am trying to install the simulator on my iMac pc (OSversion: High Sierra 10.13.6). 
All the dependencies specified on the site have been installed to the correct version. The problem i am currently stuck with is that when i try to first compile M5 in the gem5 directory with 'scons build/ARM/gem5.opt', it stopped with errors mostly being:

```
**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3656:5: error: destructor called on non-final
      'Stats::BinaryNode<std::__1::multiplies<double> >' that has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor [-Werror,-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]**
    __data_.second().~_Tp();
    ^
```

I couldn't find any relevent answers regarding this. I hope if there are any amazing MAC gem5 developers out there can help me with this.

cheers!

Comment: Also email the mailing list. Give your gem5 git revision and exact Mac OS version. On Stack Overflow, familiarize yourself with the markdown code block syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help I myself use Ubuntu and can guarantee it works there.

Answer (score 0):

I mailed to Mr Andreas Sandberg. The answer worked for me:

"I think the compiler version you are using uses more aggressive warnings than default (and possibly a newer C++ standard than we normally use). I would suggest disabling -Werror and see if that makes a difference."

Try disabling -Werror with the next command line :
export CFLAGS="-Wno-error"

Hope work for you.